# iOS : How to refresh view in a function?

Tags: ios

I'm very very new to iOS programming but I already have a big issue I can't solve. It seems so easy.

I have a button, I click on it to change a label called `message`

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)react:(id)sender {
    int hasard ;
    hasard=3; 
    message.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 %d",hasard];    
    sleep (1);
    message.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2 %d",hasard]; 
}
```

It works well but I don't see the first `message.text` change.
When I click the button, I have to wait one second and I see `2 3`

I thought I could see `1 3`, wait a second and then see `2 3`.
What is missing? It seems so obvious.

Comment: add `[self.view setNeedsLayout];` after 1st message.text

Comment: @Sumanth that would not do anything because the thread would be suspended in between calls, and setting the text of `UITextField`s automatically handles the code necessary to redraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking the main thread (well, rather `sleep()` blocks it). If you do so, committed changes to the UI won't appear - you'll only see the final result. You have to do something else (blocking the UI is a very bad idea in terms of user experience, by the way). You can try using a timer, for example:

```
int hasard = 3;

- (void)react:(id)sender
{
     message.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 %d", hasard];
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)timer:(NSTimer *)tmr
{
     message.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2 %d", hasard];
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine .. can i pass parameters to the timer ? sorry to be so bad :)

Comment: @Fredv To answer that question: yes, you can, using the `userInfo` argument of the creation method and that of `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 6):

[`sleep()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html) will suspend the current threads execution which is the main thread so you are blocking all UI operations until the method completes. You need to schedule the second assignment to run after the specified time without blocking the current run loop. This can be achieved with GCD.

```
- (IBAction)react:(id)sender {
    int hasard ;
    hasard=3; 
    message.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 %d",hasard];

    int64_t delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        message.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2 %d",hasard];
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @joe, please let us know about the benefits of GCD here. Is it same thing as `performselector:afterdelay:` or `NSTimer: scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`?

Comment: GCD does not require you to create a method just to handle a simple text assignment and it can capture all variables in scope. If you need to support < iOS 4 then use one of the alternatives.